# json HTTP Request Body Validation patterns

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the patterns for validating a JSON body.

For instance,

```
  // I have this struct
  type Program struct {
    ProgramKey string `json:"program_key" validate:"required"`
    Active     *bool     `json:"active" validate:"required"`
  }

  // json request body
  {
    "program_key" : "example-key",
    "active" : false
  }
```

I want to run my request validation before the JSON decode error's out. But unsure if this is the best way to do it.

Because whenever I do the decode

```
   // json request body
   {
    "program_key" : "example-key",
    "active" : "false" // notice the string value here
   }
   json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&program);
```

The decode fails if the consumer sends a string false. Because the JSON decode fails to decode and assign the request. I don't mind using this as the first layer of error handling/validation. But given I can customize the error message. I don't want to expose the underlying details of the API to the consumer.

I am unable to find good patterns around this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is an error from `json.Decode`, depending on the error, the struct you parse results into may still contain some results. From the Go docs, if you try to parse a JSON string with the wrong type `json.Decode` will return an error of type [`UnmarshalTypeError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalTypeError). Something like:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Program struct {
    ProgramKey string `json:"program_key"`
    Active     bool   `json:"active"`
}

func (p *Program) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("&Program{ProgramKey: %s, Active: %t", p.ProgramKey, p.Active)
}

func ParseProgram(jsonStr string) (*Program, error) {
    var p *Program
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &p)
    if err != nil {
        switch err.(type) {
        case *json.UnmarshalTypeError:
            // Maybe log this or build a debug message from it.
            fmt.Println(err)
        default:
            return p, err
        }
    }
    // Inspect P further since it might still contain valid info.
    // ...
    return p, nil
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `
        {
            "program_key": "example-key",
            "active": "false"
        }
    `
    p, err := ParseProgram(jsonStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Produces:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Program.active of type bool
&Program{ProgramKey: example-key, Active: false
```

Notice that the `p` in main still has the `ProgramKey` field populated.